# Hibernate выбор из mapedsuperclass одинаковых полей

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

Привет всем!
Есть:

```
1) Entitybase

    --> Entity1
    --> Entirt2
2) Entity3
```

Entity1,2 наследуются (mapedsuperclass) от entitybase, Entity3 имеет ссылку на Entitybase.

Строю запрос от Entity3 + alias на entitybase.
Hibernate автоматически делает left join entity1 и 2.

Примрно так:

```
Select .... From e3 this
    Inner join eb aliasbase
    Left join e1 alias1
    Left join e2 alias2
```

Указал в projectionlist ***имя поля из entity1/entity2 которого нет в EntityBase* и оно пришло!**

```
Select ...., alias1.name From e3 this
     Inner join eb aliasbase
     Left join e1 alias1
     Left join e2 alias2
```

При этом alias я не знал и не указал. hibernate вероятно нашел поле по имени. Алиас таблицы в SQL взят ,вероятно ,по первому вхождению поля.

**Вопрос : если в e1 и e2 есть одинаково названные поля(пусть будут "name")
Как их правильно считать? Или как узнать/задать алиасы автоматически добавленных entity1 и entity2?**

К примеру:

```
 Select ...., alias1.name, aluas2.name From e3 this
      Inner join eb aliasbase
      Left join e1 alias1
      Left join e2 alias2
```

Или можно даже так:

```
  Select ...., my_alias3.name, my_alias4.name From e3 this
      Inner join eb aliasbase
      Left join e1 alias1
      Left join e2 alias2
      Left join e1 my_alias3
      Left join e2 my_alias4
```

Спасибо

Comment: Select ...., my_alias3.name `n1`, my_alias4.name `n2` From e3 this  а там уже `.getString("n1")`

Comment: Ммм... @and Как сделать left join entity1, entity2 к основному запросу без subquery?

Comment: Не понятно чего вы хотите. И разве можно mappedsuperclass использовать в запросах? Это же ни коим образом не entity.

Comment: В моем примере , к Entity3 присоединена общая сущность EntityBase и соответсвенно есть досту к общим полям e1 и e2. Я же хочу получить доступ к уникальным плям e1 и e2.